# ElasticSearch backup and restore

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

as a PoC we are looking to define a method of backing up and restoring elasticsearch clusters that are running on AWS EC2 instances. The clusters each have more than 1 node running on different EC2 instances.

Being new to elasticsearch the main method that appears is to use the elasticsearch snapshot API, however are there any issues with using AWS Backup as a service to take snapshots of the EC2 instances themselves?

The restoration process would then be to create a new EC2 instance from a specified AMI that is created by the AWS Backup snapshot of the original EC2 instance running elasticsearch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that, but it has some drawbacks and it is not recommended.

First, to make a snapshot of **any** instance, you will need to stop your **entire** elasticsearch cluster. If, for example, your cluster has 3 nodes, you will need to stop all your nodes and make the snapshots, you can't make a snapshot of only one node, you will need to make a snapshot of the entire cluster at the same moment, always.

Second, since you are making snapshots of the entire instance, not only the elasticsearch data, you lose the flexiblity of restoring the data in another place, or restore just part of the data, you need to restore everything. Also, if you make snapshots everyday at 23:00 P.M. and for some reason you need to restore your snapshot at 17:00 P.M. next day, everything stored after your last snapshot will be lost.

And Third, even if you took those precautions, there is no guarantee that you will not have problems or corrupted data.

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html):

> The only reliable way to back up a cluster is by using the snapshot
> and restore functionality

Since you are using AWS, the best approach would be to use a s3 repository for your snapshots and automate your backups using the [snapshot lifecycle managment](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-snapshot-lifecycle-management.html) in kibana.